# Get original ArrayList from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

How can I retrieve the underlying ArrayList from an ArrayAdapter in Android?

Is this possible or do I need to keep track of them seperately?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
ArrayList<String> underlying =
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to get the underlying `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> underlying =  = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < adapter .getCount(); i++)
    underlying .add(adapter .getItem(i));
```

Comment: Is this the ideal solution?

Comment: this way you actually get a clone of the original arrayList, so it depends on your needs.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: yes, it depends on the needs. So I don't say that its an ideal solution, but can be used to get the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you don't have this feature, you can easily create an adapter that fits your needs by extending the BaseAdapter instead .

just send the list to the adapter via its CTOR, and you can change it later from outside of the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged when you are done.

word of caution though: if you have the original instance of the list of the adapter, you should handle multi-threading issues (or access it only via the UI thread), and if you modify it (especially add/remove items) you should always call notifyDataSetChanged .

Answer (score 0):

Different approach but may well meet your needs: Extend your adapter from "ArrayAdapter", declare the array externally, then pass the array in to the constructor when creating the adapter

```
//Adapter Declaration
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyType> {}

//Externally declared ArrayList:
ArrayList<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();

//Adapter Instantiation (in your activity)
MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, myList);
```

Answer (score -2):

It is easy. You need to get your Adapter and use clear() method.

```
 ((myArrayAdapter)myListView.getAdapter()).clear();
```